# Who is the father of Shathabisha, the king who tried to kill Sati?

Tags: shiva-purana, sati-goddess

In Devon Ke Dev Mahadev serial, I see that Shathabisha was rejected from entering the Brahma Lok to meet Brahma Dev.
He and his father tries to harm Daksha Prajapati.
His father organizes a Ritual and invites Sati to be present for that.
While Sati was in her journey with her sisters (Diti and Aditi), Shathabisha tries to kill them by sending Snakes.
Later he sends some armed people to kill her and Siva continuously protects Her.

I want to know whether the Shathabisha was the Asterism or some other Brahman / King with that name and who was his father?

Comment: This serial has lot of stories which are not mentioned in any scriptures. These stories are either folk lores or self created to gain viewership. In the TV serial, Shatabhisha was shown as the son of Rishi Angiras but I couldn't find any such reference anywhere. However, Shatabhisha is said to be Nakshatra and moon's position in this nakshatra according to astrology affects on the personality traits of a person. According to another source, Satabhisha is said to be one of Daksha's daughter who is married to Chandra.

Comment: Its sad that nowadays people just show anything in mythological serials whether they have any scriptural reference or not just. I will be happy if somebody can find if Shatabhisha's story as shown by the TV serial actually exists.